# Can't select drop-down menu in Python app

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

I have a script to scrape values from a website, with a drop-down hover menu in which the parent menu needs to be hovered over and a drop-down option selected. This was working perfectly up until a few days ago. But now is failing randomly.

This is my current code:

```
def select_dropdown():

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.menu.menuTopCenter > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a")))
    investment = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.menu.menuTopCenter > ul > li:nth-child(3) > a")))
    actions.move_to_element(investment).perform()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
         ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li:nth-child(3) > div > div:nth-child(1) > a"))).click()
```

See the HTML below for the parent menu:

```
 <a class="menuLink mainMenuItem" href="#" renderstyle="NONE" action="" 
 controller="" clientmodulesubid="0" renderlocation="" 
 clearcontentheader="False" 
 lobsystemuserids="Ls6EVzOdmMPVcdHshYcUbg==">Investment</a>
```

See the HTML below for the option to be selected (sub_menu):

```
 <a class="menuLink mainMenuItem" href="#" renderstyle="REPLACE" action="Index" 
 controller="Portfolio" clientmodulesubid="6109" 
 renderlocation="contentHeaderContainer" clearcontentheader="True" 
 lobsystemuserids="Ls6EVzOdmMPVcdHshYcUbg==">Investment summary</a>
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SChogle/PycharmProjects/Web Scraping All Sites (With BDay).py", line 55, in <module>
    select_dropdown()
  File "C:/Users/SChogle/PycharmProjects/Web Scraping All Sites (With BDay).py", line 29, in select_dropdown
    ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li:nth-child(3) > div > div:nth-child(1) > a"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\SChogle\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

This is the full HTML for the parent menu and all sub-menus:

```
 <li class="has-children">
<a class="menuLink mainMenuItem" href="#" 
 renderstyle="NONE" action="" controller="" clientmodulesubid="0" 
 renderlocation="" clearcontentheader="False" 
 lobsystemuserids="8qWAwlpk6Jdje8MVVaH1Tw==">Investment</a>

<div class="subMenu"> 
 <div>

<a class="menuLink mainMenuItem" href="#" renderstyle="REPLACE" 
 action="Index" controller="Portfolio" clientmodulesubid="6109" 
 renderlocation="contentHeaderContainer" clearcontentheader="True" 
 lobsystemuserids="8qWAwlpk6Jdje8MVVaH1Tw==">Investment summary</a>
</div>

<div>
<a class="menuLink mainMenuItem" href="#" renderstyle="REPLACE" 
 action="GetLazyTransactionHistoryByAccountGroup" controller="Transactions" 
 clientmodulesubid="6108" renderlocation="contentHeaderContainer" 
 clearcontentheader="True" 
 lobsystemuserids="8qWAwlpk6Jdje8MVVaH1Tw==">Transaction history</a>
</div>

<div> 
 <a class="menuLink mainMenuItem" href="#" renderstyle="REPLACE" 
 action="LoadIncomeDistribution" controller="IncomeDistribution" 
 clientmodulesubid="7005" renderlocation="contentHeaderContainer" 
 clearcontentheader="True" lobsystemuserids="8qWAwlpk6Jdje8MVVaH1Tw==">Income 
 distribution</a>
</div>

<div>
<a class="menuLink mainMenuItem" href="#" 
 renderstyle="REPLACE" action="PortfolioFees" controller="Fees" 
 clientmodulesubid="6159" renderlocation="contentHeaderContainer" 
 clearcontentheader="True" lobsystemuserids="8qWAwlpk6Jdje8MVVaH1Tw==">Advisor 
 charges</a>
</div>

<div><a class="menuLink mainMenuItem" href="#" 
 renderstyle="REPLACE" action="GetRecurringInstructionsDetail" 
 controller="RecurringInstructions" clientmodulesubid="6158" 
 renderlocation="contentHeaderContainer" clearcontentheader="True" 
 lobsystemuserids="8qWAwlpk6Jdje8MVVaH1Tw==">Recurring instructions</a>
</div> 

<div>
<a class="menuLink mainMenuItem" href="#" renderstyle="REPLACE" 
 action="GenerateAdHocWebStatement_SAIP" controller="AdHocWebStatement" 
 clientmodulesubid="6121" renderlocation="contentHeaderContainer" 
 clearcontentheader="True" lobsystemuserids="8qWAwlpk6Jdje8MVVaH1Tw==">Investor 
 statement</a>
</div>

<div>
<a class="menuLink mainMenuItem" href="#" 
 renderstyle="REPLACE" action="GenerateAdHocWebStatement_SAIP" 
 controller="AdHocWebStatement" clientmodulesubid="8939" 
 renderlocation="contentHeaderContainer" clearcontentheader="True" 
 lobsystemuserids="8qWAwlpk6Jdje8MVVaH1Tw==">Tax certificate</a>
</div>
</div> 
 </li>
```

I think MAYBE what is happening is that the script is trying to find the element before the page has loaded, but I am unsure. As I said it works sometimes and fails other times.

Comment: Is it possible to share url?

Comment: Where and what error do you get?

Comment: Did you try to increase timeout? Can you share full HTML with menu and sub menus?

Comment: @Sers yeah, I have tried to increase timeout to like 50 seconds, still no luck. I have included the full HTML with the parent menu and all sub-menus above. Let me know if thats what you wanted? Or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 1):

Try `select_menu` method below:

```
def select_menu(menu: str = None, submenu: str = None):
    menu_locator = f"//div[contains(@class,'menu')]//a[.='{menu}']"
    submenu_locator = f"{menu_locator}/ancestor::li[1]/div[@class='subMenu']//a[.='{submenu}']"

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

    wait.until(lambda d: d.execute_script("return document.readyState === 'complete' && jQuery.active === 0;"))

    menu_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, menu_locator)))
    actions.move_to_element(menu_element).perform()

    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, submenu_locator))).click()
```

How to call method:

```
select_menu(menu="Investment", submenu="Investment summary")
```

Comment: thanks so much for the answer, but unfortunately still getting a timeout error. For some reason it cannot find that parent menu. I have tried clicking a button on the page which refreshes the page. and then the parent menu is almost always found. However, there is an issue reliably finding the "refresh" button as it throws an element click intercepted error

Comment: I have added a picture of what the menu looks like, its a hover menu. so hovering the mouse over "Investment" will bring up all the options below

Answer (score 0):

You can try debugging to narrow to solution with these steps:
1. Retry the same block of code using try catch:

```
count=0, max=5;
while(true){    
try{
    //drop down click
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    if(count++==max) throw e;
    }
}
```

2. also you may try reloading page and then executing till its success.

   driver.navigate().refresh();